# Why does this for-loop not process all elements of the array?

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop

Given the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

asteriskFiles=("sip.conf" "extensions.conf")

for asteriskFile in $asteriskFiles
do
    # backup current configuration file
    cp somepath/${asteriskFile} test/
    echo "test"
done
```

This gives me the output "test" only once, so the loop runs only once instead of two times (two entries in asteriskFiles array). What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 11):

An illustration:

```
$ asteriskFiles=("sip.conf" "extensions.conf")
$ echo $asteriskFiles # is equivalent to echo ${asteriskFiles[0]}
sip.conf
$ echo "${asteriskFiles[@]}"
sip.conf extensions.conf
```

Note that the quotes are important. `echo ${asteriskFiles[@]}` might seem to work, but bash would wordsplit on whitespace if any of your files had whitespace in them.

Comment: +1 for a great explanation of the problem without spoon-feeding the final answer.

Comment: I had to look at the answer twice, but I understand, thank you very much! So by default $array maps to the first element and not the whole array. Strange syntax with the [@] for me though. Anyway, it works and I know it now ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Write the beginning of your loop like this

```
for asteriskFile in "${asteriskFiles[@]}"
```

Answer (score 2):

#### The Probem

The *asteriskFiles* variable holds an array. If you dereference it like a scalar, you only get the first element of the array.

#### The Solution

You want to use the correct [shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to access all the subscript elements. For example:

```
$ echo "${asteriskFiles[@]}"
sip.conf extensions.conf
```

The @ subscript (when correctly quoted) will expand to the properly-tokenized elements of your array, which your for-loop will then be able to iterate over.